# Finding nearest image element and refresh image source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <img name="previewImage" alt="" src="" style="max-height:300px;max-width :350px;">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button name="btnPushPhoto" type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1">Push</button>
        <button name="btnRemovePhoto" type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the remove photo button, I'm able to set my image to null (in the server side), however at the client side, I'm having some difficulties locating the image tag, and refresh it.

```
$(document).on("click", "[name=btnRemovePhoto]", function () {
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the photo?");
    if (r == true) {
        var uniqueId = $(this).data('uniqueId');
        $.post($("#remove-photo-url").val(), { uniqueId: uniqueId })
            .done(function () {
                //var img = $(this).closest('[name=previewImage]');
                var img = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name=previewImage]');
                console.log(img);                            
                img.attr('src', '');
                img.attr('src', img.attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
            });

    }

});
```

Nothing seems to happen here. No error in the browser's console.

This is the output of `console.log(img);`

```
[prevObject: x.fn.x.init[0], context: undefined, selector: "[name=previewImage]"]
```

Comment: What does console.log(img) output?

Comment: The attribute selector needs to be [name='btnRemovePhoto'] (single quotes in this case)

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: `this` inside `done()` callback refers to jqXHR option object

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35366918/3733816

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the `$(this)` in some variable before post request since inside the callback, this refers to the jqXHR object of the Ajax call, not the element the event handler was bound to :

```
_this = $(this);
```

Then you could use `parents()` instead :

```
var img = _this.parents('.col-md-4').find('[name="previewImage"]');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[name=btnRemovePhoto]", function () {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the photo?");
        if (r == true) {
            var uniqueId = $(this).data('uniqueId');
            var $this = $(this); //Insert this line
            $.post($("#remove-photo-url").val(), { uniqueId: uniqueId })
                .done(function () {
                    var img = $this.closest("div.col-md-4").find("img"); //USE $this
                    console.log(img);                            
                    img.attr('src', '');
                    img.attr('src', img.attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
                });

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move `img` definition before the `$.post` function:

```
$(document).on("click", "[name=btnRemovePhoto]", function () {
    var img = $(this).parent().parent().find('[name=previewImage]');
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the photo?");
    if (r == true) {
        var uniqueId = $(this).data('uniqueId');
        $.post($("#remove-photo-url").val(), { uniqueId: uniqueId })
        .done(function () {
            //var img = $(this).closest('[name=previewImage]');
            console.log(img);                            
            img.attr('src', '');
            img.attr('src', img.attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery selector "closest"

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

```
           $(document).on("click", "[name=btnRemovePhoto]", function () {
                var clickedButton = $(this);
                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the photo?");
                if (r == true) {
                    var uniqueId = $(this).data('uniqueId');
                    $.post($("#remove-photo-url").val(), { uniqueId: uniqueId })
                        .done(function () {
                            var img = clickedButton .closest("div.col-md-4").find("img");
                            console.log(img);                            
                            img.attr('src', '');
                            img.attr('src', img.attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
                        });

                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are searching/looking at the relationship needs to be edited slightly. There are a few jquery methods that may help but I usually like to map out the relationships in my head like below:

```
<div name="PARENT_of_PARENT_of_X">
                    <div name="Sibling_of_PARENT_of_X OR child_of_PARENT_of_PARENT_of_X>
                        <img name="Child_of_SIBLING_of_PARENT_of_X OR CHILD_of_PARENT_of_PARENT_of_X" />
                    </div>
                    <div name="PARENT_of_X">
                        <button ></button>
                        <button name="SOURCE X" >Remove</button>
                    </div>
</div>
```